# Promise.all in useEffect hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I'm dealing with a use case where two API calls are made one after the other. The second API call is made by taking a value from the first API call response. I was able to use `Promise.all` with *axios* in my **React** application.

Is there a better way to call the APIs in chain in `useEffect` hook? I'm open to suggestions or recommendations. Could anyone please help?

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    const getFirstResponse = async () => {
      try {
        return await axios.get('http://first-api', {
          params: { carId: id },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    };

    const firstResponse = await getFirstResponse();

    const getSecondResponse = async () => {
      try {
        return await axios.get('http://second-api', {
          params: { carName: firstResponse.data?.carName },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    };

    const secondResponse = await getSecondResponse();

    Promise.all([firstResponse, secondResponse])
      .then(function (values) {
        console.log(`values`, values);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }, []);
```

Comment: Please fix your script (and therefor fix the broken syntax highlighting)

Comment: i do not understand why do you use `promise.all` at all in your case

Comment: I want to initiate the second api call only when the first api call has a success response. Right now, I see that both API calls are made in parallel @Max

Comment: You're awaiting them, they aren't made in parallel.

Comment: Don't ever `catch (error) { return error; }`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.all` is completely superfluous here.

It is a tool for handling promises that are running **in parallel** not in series.

The argument you pass to it should be an array of promises. `firstResponse` and `secondResponse` are the values that have been unwrapped from promises by `await`.

Just use `firstResponse` and `secondResponse` directly.

```
const secondResponse = await getSecondResponse();
console.log([firstResponse, secondResponse]);
```

For that matter, creating the nested `async` functions and having multiple `try/catch` blocks that do the same thing just makes the code harder to read.

You can reduce the whole thing down to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
        try {
            const firstResponse = await axios.get('http://first-api', {
                params: { carId: id },
            });
            const secondResponse = await axios.get('http://second-api', {
                params: { carName: firstResponse.data?.carName },
            });
            console.log(`values`, [firstResponse, secondResponse]);
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
      }
    asyncFunction();
}, []);
```

Comment: Neat and concise! I tried tweaking the first api response to fail, the second API call did not went through which is exactly the behavior I wanted it to work. May I know how this logic worked, halting the second API call when the first is failed in your case? @Quentin

Comment: @Bergi — Well, technically a function or nothing, but good point, I hadn't spotted that error in the original code. Updated.

Comment: @coderpc Well that's what `await` does

Comment: @coderpc — Oh, I made a mistake when transcribing your code. Because I moved the try/catch: if the first request throws an error then that error is no longer passed as the value for the second request. The whole sequence aborts instead.

Answer (score 0):

another possible way to get the result using Promise.all, but I like Quentin`s answer

```
try {
    const responses = await Promise.all([body1, body2].map(async body => {
        return await axios.get(body.endpoint, body.params);
    }))
} catch(error) {
    return error;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. The params for the second request need to include values from the first response.

Comment: oh, i forgot, ok

Answer (score 0):

How about you write a custom hook that handles *loading* and *error* state so you don't have to rewrite it for each component?

1. Avoid defining complex functions inside of `useEffect`
2. Separate api calls into individual functions. This makes them reusable in other areas of your app
3. Don't return errors on the resolved branch of your Promise. Instead let them reject and allow the caller to handle appropriately

Let's look at `MyComponent`. All complexity is removed and the component is only concerned with the three possible states of the asynchronous call -

```js
// MyComponent.js

import { useAsync } from "./hooks"
import { fetchCarWithDetails } from "./api"

function MyComponent({ carId }) {
  const {loading, error, result} =
    useAsync(fetchCarWithDetails, [carId])  // reusable hook

  // loading...
  if (loading)
    return <p>Loading...</p>

  // error...
  if (error)
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>

  // result...
  return <pre>
    {JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}
  </pre>
}
```

Our reusable api functions are defined in our `api` module -

```js
// api.js

import axios from "axios"

function fetchCar(carId) {
  return axios
    .get('http://first-api', {params: {carId}})
    .then(r => r.data)
}

function fetchDetails(carName) {
  return axios
    .get('http://second-api', {params: {carName}})
    .then(r => r.data)
}

async function fetchCarWithDetails(carId) {
  const car = await fetchCar(carId)
  const details = await fetchDetails(car.carName)
  return { car, details }
}

export { fetchCar, fetchDetails, fetchCarWithDetails }
```

Reusable hooks are defined in our `hooks` module -

```js
// hooks.js

function useAsync(f, [_0, _1, _2, _3, _4]) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  useEffect(_ => {
    setLoading(true)
    Promise.resolve(f(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, [f, _0, _1, _2, _3, _4])
  return {loading, error, result}
}

export { useAsync }
```